# I tried to prove $\sum_{n=0}^∞ \frac{n^2}{2^n} = 6$ but I feel that my proof is long. Can anyone provide an alternate proof?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Some parts of the text might not be clear so please ask about them in the comments. Sorry for the uploaded image as it was taking a long time for me to write the whole proof.

[image: img]

Comment: +1 for the photo

Comment: Please type your attempts here. Do not attach images.

Comment: Lol for the pic

Comment: @Jochen Me too :)

Comment: It's an original version of a Brillant Mind when Nash does maths on the window...

Comment: @CélioAugusto His attempt is better documented than my birth date in state papers. Leave him alone. And the question is interesting too. However, whenever I try to check his attempt, I stop at his legs and cannot move. :)

Comment: very good job!!! Its a bit long but it seems truly original

Comment: [This](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html) webpage might help.

Comment: [Different Methods to compute the sum $\displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}{1 \over k^{2}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1k2-basel-pro) has, for the time being, $\displaystyle\large 55$ answers !!!.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usual short proof is$$\begin{align}\sum_{n\ge0}x^n&=\frac{1}{1-x}\\\implies\sum_{n\ge0}n^2x^n&=x\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n\ge0}x^n\right)\\&=x\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}-\frac{1}{1-x}\right)\\&=\frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3}\end{align}$$with $x=\tfrac12$. It looks like your approach is more similar to a different one that can also be made reasonably concise:$$\sum_{n\ge0}n^2x^n=\sum_{n\ge0}\left(2\binom{n}{2}+n\right)x^n=\left(x^2\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+x\frac{d}{dx}\right)\sum_{n\ge0}x^n=\frac{2x^2}{(1-x)^3}+\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}.$$